# What is an expired account in SonosAPI and which error code should be returned?

Tags: sonos

Our music service is rejected by Sonos because no expired account is provided.

In Sonos Labs, Under Development & Submit section C: QUALITY ASSURANCE & PERFORMANCE, you should provide at least 1 account that reflects other types of accounts you support. 
I provided a disabled account which returns the 'LoginDisabled' error code when this account is used. This seems to be not enough.

In the documentation about 'Standard Error Handling' (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/110), I don't see any error code to return for an expired account.

So my question is: What is an expired account in Sonos, which error code should we return for an expired account, and is it really necessary to provide an expired account to succeed Sonos tests? There's nothing in de submit section about an expired account.

Comment: The documentation refers to an error code for an expired trial account, where the error is supposed to be LoginUnauthorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Python self-test suite (at the bottom of [this page](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=docs))? The following configuration parameters are requested:

```
[Accounts]
supportedaccount =
supportedpassword =
unsupportedaccount =
unsupportedpassword =
expiredtrialaccount =
expiredtrialpassword =
unsupportedterritoryaccount =
unsupportedterritorypassword =
```

I'm only just starting to develop our solution here, but returning a Client.LoginUnauthorized SOAP fault passes this test. This is documented [here](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/110).